# Is there any way to get List of Objects filtered by jsonb field from raw sql in Ebean

Tags: java, postgresql, jsonb, ebean

I try to get some records from DB that equals a few conditions(one of them is jsonB field). When I try do it in postgres - its works. But when I do it from java code I got postgres cast error and I don't know how to resolve it.

First of all i tried to use List then I make string from this list as in the code below. I tried to cast tables values to jsonB via "::jsonb" or "to_jsonb()" but it didn't work. The error is: "PSQLException: ERROR: statement does not exist: jsonb = character varying"

```java
ArrayList tableId = new ArrayList(){
    {
        add(1);
        add(2);
    }
};
String tables = tableIds.stream().map(id -> "\'" + String.valueOf(id) + "\'").collect(Collectors.joining(","));

String sql = "SELECT id, date, table_info where date = :date and table_info -> 'id' in(:tableIds)";

            RawSql rawSql = RawSqlBuilder
                    .parse(sql)
                    .create();

            Query<Booking> query = Ebean.find(Booking.class);
            bookings = query.setRawSql(rawSql)
                    .setParameter("date",  date )
                    .setParameter("tableIds", tableIds)
                    .findSet();
```

SQL code

```sql
select * from Booking
where date = '2019-11-07' and table_info -> 'id' in('1', '2');
```

I want to get all records by the date and where field "id" in table_info equals tableId list

Comment: Return the `id` as text: `table_info ->> ...`

Comment: Thank you, it works, another time I will read documentations with great attention